# Gridview to Pdf using XMLworker cuts off text

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itext

This code does export my gridview to pdf but some of the text gets cut off. What is determining the width of my gridview/table in the pdf document?

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Equipment.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();


    GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    frm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
    frm.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);//create a document object

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);//get a pdf writer instance

    pdfDoc.Open();//open the document
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);//invoke XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXhtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream)

    pdfDoc.Close();//close the document

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the specific HTML it is hard to reproduce your exact issue. I would start by looking at the HTML generated by the `RenderControl`. In the absence of any specific `width` commands `XmlWorker` will just try to fit things on to the page based on the content. If all text/objects within a column have a maximum length of 50 then that column will essentially have that for a width (plus some padding possibly). Repeat this for every column and you've got the width of the table. If that is wider than the document then columns will be shrunk by wrapping text until it fits.